# How to use a boxplot with grouping and multiple variables

Tags: r, data-visualization, data-transformation, boxplot

[image]

I am trying to create a graph in R that has 7 variables on the x axis, and size on the y axis.  Each variable has 2 treatments and sex (drug 1/2 & M/F). I am struggling to understand how to:

1. manipulate my data and
2. plot the data.

The above regions are the volumes of 7 body regions &
The IDs are my different subjects.
The data is non-repetitive; however, subjects with similar "TREATMENT" background colors are from the same litters.
Litter 1 (A-G & N-T)
Litter 2 (H-M & U-Z)

I would like to visually show the different body region sizes by treatment and sex. I assume a grouped boxplot would be the nicest visually but I am open to other ideas.  A sample of the data is below:

```
    dput(MRI_hh)
structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "s", "T", "U", 
"V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"), Treatment = c("Blue", "Blue", "Blue", 
"Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", 
"Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Blue", 
"Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red"), Sex = c("Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male"), `Region 1` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26
), `Region 2` = c(15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40), 
    `Region 3` = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
    17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30), 
    `Region 4` = c(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
    19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33
    ), `Region 5` = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 
    60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 
    125, 130, 135), `Region 6` = c(12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 
    26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 
    56, 58, 60, 62), `Region 7` = c(2, 8, 14, 20, 26, 32, 38, 
    44, 50, 56, 62, 68, 74, 80, 86, 92, 98, 104, 110, 116, 122, 
    128, 134, 140, 146, 152)), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is kind of an idea I was thinking of. In the sample set, I only included one of the two groups. I also have an exposure timing variable in my total dataset.
[image]

Comment: Notice to potential close-voters: I believe the [tag:data-visualization] aspect predominates here, so this appears to be on-topic to me.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your data, ideally by including the output from `dput(yourdataframe)`? See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6098/1352.

Comment: It is going to be really long. Is that a problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could post a subset, like the first 20 rows? That would not be a problem. And by all means, do keep the table in your post - non-R-users may be able to chime in, and a table will be more enlightening to them than a `dput`.

Comment: The current snippet does not parse in my R. Please run it through your R to ensure the code is working. (Also, best to format as code, see the buttons above the edit window.)

Comment: Should work now.

Comment: Can you say what the data are?  Is each row a different person / company / criter (etc.)?  Ie, are these repeated measures?  What is the outcome?  What are the treatments?

Comment: How many boxplots do you want to make altogether? // What are the constraints? It seems you will have several panels of boxplots; how many boxplots do you want to put in each panel? What comparisons are most important to you? Are you able to include color graphs in your report?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add litter to your dataset.  Then reshape your data into 'long' form, so you have two matching datasets.  From there, you can plot the individual variables with boxplots, but not the full combination, because you have only 1 datum per combination.  Instead, you could make a line plot for each mouse, using different symbols and colors to indicate what groups they belong to.

```
d = structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
              ... 
              "tbl", "data.frame"))
d$litter = ifelse(d$ID%in%c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
                            "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "s", "T"), 
                  "l1", "l2")

dl = reshape(d, varying=names(d)[4:10], v.names="volume", timevar="region",
             idvar="ID", direction="long")

windows()
  layout(matrix(1:4, nrow=2))
  boxplot(volume~Treatment, dl)
  boxplot(volume~Sex, dl)
  boxplot(volume~litter, dl)
  boxplot(volume~region, dl)

window()
  plot(1:7,1:7, xlim=c(1,7), ylim=range(dl$volume), type="n", xlab="region",
       ylab="volume")
  for(i in 1:26){
    lines(1:7, d[i,4:10], lwd=2, col=d$Treatment[i], 
          lty=ifelse(d$litter[i]=="l1",1,3))
    points(1:7, d[i,4:10], lwd=2, col=d$Treatment[i], 
           pch=ifelse(d$Sex[i]=="Male",3,1))
  }
```

[image]

[image]

These data look awfully suspicious to me.

Comment: Thank you for this idea but I was thinking more of something like this.[https://reverton.net/index/2017/08/03/visualization-of-survey-data/]

Comment: That's a bar plot, @ErikaBauer.  I'm not really impressed by it.  If you wanted to display means, it might be OK... with error bars.  But even then, it wouldn't respect the fact that the measures are nested within organisms (mice?).

Comment: I like your idea of showing descriptive stats first!! I would like to showcase each of the regions individually instead of on one graph. I attached a better idea of what I am trying to create

Comment: You can do that if you want.

Comment: How do you code multiple graphs together and then in a larger group and with one legend for the whole thing?

Comment: @ErikaBauer, [stats.SE] is a site for questions about statistics (etc).  Questions about how to get R to do something go on [SO].

Comment: I was wondering. Is a two-factor ANOVA not the correct way to determine if there is a difference in the regions for treatment and sex.  You brought up a point that groups of my mice are in the same litter, so wouldn't my data be paired?

Comment: @ErikaBauer, that should be asked in a new question.  You have measurements nested in mice nested in litters.  There is more than pairing going on here.